# how to hide trace tag in eclipse(Android)

Tags: eclipse, android-logcat

How to remove unnecessary trace or tag in eclipse(Android). Like this trace

```
05-02 06:16:49.093: W/Trace(1227): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-02 06:16:49.093: W/Trace(1227): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-02 06:16:49.164: W/Trace(1227): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-02 06:16:49.164: W/Trace(1227): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-02 06:16:49.201: I/Choreographer(1227): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too 
05-02 06:16:49.362: W/Trace(1227): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-02 06:16:49.362: W/Trace(1227): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-02 06:16:49.451: W/Trace(1227): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-02 06:16:49.451: W/Trace(1227): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-02 06:16:49.491: I/Choreographer(1227): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-02 06:16:49.532: W/Trace(1227): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-02 06:16:49.532: W/Trace(1227): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-02 06:16:49.591: W/Trace(1227): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-02 06:16:49.591: W/Trace(1227): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-02 06:16:49.632: I/Choreographer(1227): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: [Android LogCat Filter for multiple tags in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12642447/1856738), [How to filter messages to Logcat in eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14546737/1856738)

Answer (score 0):

use the adb logcat -v time | grep "your tag" to filter the log you want to see.